# How to form #define constant name in C?

Tags: c

I have a list of #defines in header file.
e.g

```
#define NUM1 123
#define NUM2 456
#define NUM3 789
...
#define NUM1000  111213
```

In my function I get an `int` argument `arg`. The value of `arg` can be between  1 to 1000.
based of the arg value I want to assign above defines to a variable. 
i.e

```
void func(int arg){
    if (arg == 1) {var = NUM1;}
    ....
    if (arg == 50) {var = NUM50;}
    ....
    if (arg == 1000) {var = NUM1000;}
}
```

How can I achieve this without using if or switch statement?
I tried using char array to form `#define` constant name:

```
void func(int arg){
    char name[10];
    sprintf(name,"NUM%d",arg);
    var = name;
}
```

But I don't see the expected value.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can’t really do that in C. Make a big lookup table and use that.

Comment: This obviously is an XY problem. Please describe the problem you are trying to solve this way, we can then help you find a way which is possible. At a guess, that would be an array.

Comment: You could use `var = someArray[arg]`.

Comment: If `NUM1000` was `332790`, I'd say use `void func(int arg) { var = (arg - 1) * 333 + 123; }`

Answer (score 2):

> How can I achieve this without using if or switch statement ?

**You can put all 1000 constants in an array** and then use `arg` to select the one you want.

```
int list[1000] = {NUM1, NUM2, NUM3, NUM4...NUM1000};

void func(int arg){
    var = list[arg - 1];   // use arg-1 because C arrays start from zero
}
```

> How to form #define constant name in C?

**You can't, and if you could it wouldn't help you.** Macros created with #define are handled by the preprocessor. That is, before your code is sent to the compiler itself, the preprocessor scans through it and replaces each macro name (e.g. `NUM1`) with the corresponding value (e.g. `123`). The resulting code is then passed on to the compiler, so the compiler never even sees the macro names. So even if you *could* somehow create the macro name at dynamically at run time, there'd be no way to connect that name back to the value that was associated with it in the source code.

Comment: This the 'only' sane way to do it — at least, it is the simplest and most reliable way of doing it, once you've got the array initialized correctly.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes, you're right of course -- updated with a comment to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with `#define`s. Just use one array to define you constants and access them through your function.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int KNums[] = {
        123, // 1
        456, // 2
        789, // 3
        //...  fill in the missing elements
        111213 // 1000
};
static_assert(sizeof KNums / sizeof *KNums == 1000,
        "You need 1000 elements for this to work");

int var;

void func(int arg) {
    assert((1 <= arg) && (arg <= 1000));
    var = KNums[arg - 1];
}

int main(void) {
    func(3);
    printf("%d\n", var);
}
```